# Parser(4324): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Unknown of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to set up a app to connect to an external database so I can push and pull 
data, I decided to use the following tutorial to do so (link below). I copied and pasted the code and completed the set up, I am able to push data to my database but unable to pull due to the error in Logcat in the title.

Thanks you in advance for your help.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

```
    03-06 16:53:15.395: E/JSON Parser(4324): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Unknown of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    03-06 16:53:15.405: I/Choreographer(4324): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    03-06 16:53:15.585: D/All Products:(4324): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
    03-06 16:53:15.655: W/System.err(4324): org.json.JSONException: No value for products
    03-06 16:53:15.725: W/System.err(4324):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
    03-06 16:53:15.725: W/System.err(4324):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
    03-06 16:53:15.766: W/System.err(4324):     at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:132)
    03-06 16:53:15.795: W/System.err(4324):     at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
    03-06 16:53:15.795: W/System.err(4324):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    03-06 16:53:15.865: W/System.err(4324):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    03-06 16:53:15.865: W/System.err(4324):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    03-06 16:53:15.865: W/System.err(4324):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    03-06 16:53:15.875: W/System.err(4324):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    03-06 16:53:15.875: W/System.err(4324):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    03-06 16:53:15.965: I/Choreographer(4324): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    03-06 16:53:16.105: I/Choreographer(4324): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Use a debugger and see where things go wrong; try and solve it, and if you can't, _then_ ask for help with all the relevant info.

Comment: can you post your error trace from log cat?

Comment: I have tried for a while to debug it but have no clue what's wrong. Thanks, the logcat info has been added above